# Right-Click Windows 7 Taskbar Options Disappeared

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, context-menu

I just completed a clean install of 64 bit Windows 7 Home Premium.

After adding the old style quick launch toolbar and dragging it to the left, the right-click menu on the main area of the taskbar no longer works.  I don't get any popup menu at all.  How can I restore this popup menu?

For the avoidance of doubt - I know how to access these options through alternate means, I want to restore the right-click popup menu.

Answer (score 3):

Open explorer and go to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`

Delete `1b4dd67f29cb1962.automaticDestinations-ms`

You should now be able to pin stuff again.

Source: http://angrytechnician.wordpress.com/2010/05/24/how-to-fix-a-brokenempty-jump-list-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 2):

Go to the control panel - type Taskbar in the search. There you will have access to the taskbar options.

From there, disable the band. Then unlock it. Reenable the band. Move it around.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try this.  Strangely, the popup has returned after a reboot (I can't believe I didn't try a reboot).  Appreciate your help though :-)